# Disabling unit-test compilation in Boost.Build

Tags: bjam, boost-build

[Boost.Build](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/builtins/testing.html) documentation is quite laconic when it comes to testing.

All tests in my project are defined using `unit-test` rule.

The only property mentioned, by the documentation, is `testing.launcher`, but that can only disable tests' execution when set to `testing.launcher=true`.

**How to completely disable compilation of `unit-test` rules?** I would like to do that temporarily, for example, by setting a property from commandline. I could not find any information how to do that or any reference documentation for other `testing.*` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read most of the Boost.Build documentation and the relevant part of its code **I found no way** to temporary disable building specific rule or the set of targets (for example by matching tests' targets with a regular expression).

It is, also, worth noting, that `unit-test` was **deprecated** in favor of the new testing rules: `run`, `run-fail`, `compile`, `compile-fail`, `link`, `link-fail`.

Now, probably, I'm going to **create my own rule**, as in @GrafikRobot's answer, but instead of making the target explicit I will make the rule **empty in the presence of a certain feature**.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean disabling them by default? You can do it by adding "explicit  ;" for each unit test. If you have many such targets you can save some typing and declare a rule that does it for you, plus declaring the unit test like:

```
rule explicit-unit-test ( target : source : properties * )
{
    unit-test $(target) : $(source) : $(properties) ;
    explicit $(target) ;
}
```

If you want something else.. I guess you need to better explain your question because I can't think of what else you could want.

Answer (score 0):

I use explicit test suites for this purpose as in

```
explicit X ;
test-suite X
:
      [ run test1.cpp ]
      [ run test2.cpp ]
      [ run test3.cpp ]
      [ run test4.cpp ]
;
```

You will need to request explicitly the execution of the tests in the test-suite X using

```
bjam X
```